# Will a 4TB external hard drive work on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I'm still on XP, and was wondering will a new external hard drive still work on XP? I heard XP can only handle up to 2 TB.

Comment: Software hacks only work for internal drives of that size, I can find no way to make it work using a usb drive on XP.

Comment: What happens if you use the drive in "superfloppy" format, that is, without a partition table? Windows doesn't require a partition table on media marked as removable, and the drive will show up as a single drive letter (if there are partitions it will only use the 1st one).  Without a partition table, there should no longer be a 2TiB limit. NTFS / exFAT / ext2 all work on XP and have huge size limits!

Answer (score 3):

If it's 64-bit XP there shouldn't be a problem. But if you're running 32-bit XP, there's a limit of 2048 GB (2TB) that it will access. You can try ASR3TB+Unlocker but, I don't know if it will work on a USB connected drive. Also, Windows will reserve some of the space. So instead of 4TB you may end up with about 3.5TB

Comment: That software only works with Asrock motherboards and only internal drives.

Answer (score 0):

Many external drives can use cheap translation tricks to have less percieved sectors as larger sectors, then it works. (no 32bit big number problem).

"When the drive is inside the enclosure, it becomes a "USB mass storage device" and the firmware on the USB-SATA bridge board then presents a sector size of 4096 bytes to the host" And other methods like presenting as 2 partitions or something.

The problem with this is some software that works at low levels does not understand, just like some people (inc me) and you should avoid whatever software it is that presents the disk wrongly.
 Removal of the external and putting it on a regular sata internal then it still needs a trick to get to it all. like disk wizard translation method. There can be limited support from the makers to assist you with that, because most people have moved on to systems that fully support.

So check with the product specs and see what they say about it. Prefer to avoid it with the 32bit OS if it was just an option.  make sure the data on it is secured elsewhere. always remember that strange things can present itself before using a software that claims to "fix" some disk oddity. Do research before trying to stuff it in internal, wherein it would be a normal 4T internal (in most of these drives).

Conclusion: The translation will be transparent to the user, and things will just work like you would expect them to work, plug it in and go. Then if you start messing with it or have troubles, your going to want to know a lot more before pushing buttons on other lower level disk software, and before changing its hardware.